# Angular 7-8: exportAs directive issue

Tags: angular

I'm doing everything like described in [official docs](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#exportas), but getting the following error

```
 NullInjectorError: No provider for TemplateRef!
```

Here is my code sample:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'a-c',
  exportAs: 'ddd'
})
export class ControlledDisplayDirective {

  constructor(private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) {}

  toggle(): void {
  }
}
```

And here is a [live example](https://ng-run.com/edit/mNMQywRz0wTlajIy7EDS) for Angular 8.0.0 version.

Obviously, it is because `*` is missing, I tried to play around a bit, but the `*` does not work as well, it seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12121).

I want to accomplish the same behavior, as described in the [article](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-take-advantage-of-the-exportas-property-81374ce24d26).
Any suggestions, please?

I just can't find any notice that `exportAs` was deprecated and if it does not work, why then it is still in the documentation or it's me doing something wrong?

Comment: Nothing to do with exportAs. https://medium.com/12-developer-labors/why-we-cant-inject-teplaterref-into-a-directive-b4c50e2bb0a4

Comment: I think `TemplateRef` is not accessible in a directive only in a component, you should use `ElementRef` instead.

Comment: Okay then, it's not quite true, here is how `ngIf` works and they have `TemplateRef` in use https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8.1.1/packages/common/src/directives/ng_if.ts#L10-L228

Comment: But well, yeah, I think I got it, thanks to @ritaj

Comment: Just wrap your template in <ng-template>